# Unable to call Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision OCR API via python requests

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting a list of these errors when I execute the exact code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-print-text#create-and-run-the-sample):

`gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

`NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f193b2d9048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

`MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mike-test.cognitiveservices.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /vision/v2.1/ocr/?language=en&detectOrientation=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f193b2d9048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))`

`ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mike-test.cognitiveservices.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /vision/v2.1/ocr/?language=en&detectOrientation=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f193b2d9048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))`

This is the list errors when I execute:

`response = requests.post(ocr_url, headers=headers, params=params, data=image_data)`

The request is working from **Postman**, but when I try it from **python requests**, it gives this error.

Comment: seems to be ssl issue. Check if you can specify the tls

Comment: I didn't exactly get you, can you give me an example? @ThiagoCustodio

Comment: I'm not a python dev, but search for python and TLS, probably you'll need to specify that it's not version 1.0 then should solve your problems

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks for the advice, I tried running it on the server it worked, is not working on my machine.

Comment: are you getting a different error?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio so I analysed the domain using ssllabs, and found out that it accepts only TLS 1.2 and Windows and OSX currently ship with an older version of openSSL which sends the request using TLS 1.0. So when I tried it on a debian system with updated open SSL, it worked like a charm

Comment: great, TLS 1.0 is retired, that must be the reason of the faults

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes, thanks for your insight, such hidden issues are not easy to find sometimes.